# TypeError: Cannot access member 'slice' of undefined MongoDb Atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, slice, mongodb-atlas

I'm using Mongodb Atlas

I keep getting this error when I try to run the code
when i try to save the function as draft, it gives me this error.

runtime error during function validation

[image]

```
error: 
failed to execute source for 'node_modules/express/index.js': FunctionError: failed to execute source for 'node_modules/express/lib/express.js': FunctionError: failed to execute source for 'node_modules/body-parser/index.js': TypeError: Cannot access member 'slice' of undefined
    at getStack (node_modules/depd/index.js:374:15(33))
    at depd (node_modules/depd/index.js:118:23(13))
    at node_modules/body-parser/index.js:20:32(25)

    at require (native)
    at node_modules/express/lib/express.js:21:26(17)

    at require (native)
    at node_modules/express/index.js:18:26(15)
```

This is the version of express and Mangoose I'm using.
[image]

This is code for signup

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = require("../models/user");

// Middleware to parse the request body
app.use(express.json());

// Sign up route
app.post("/signup", async (req, res) => {
const { name, email, password } = req.body;

// Check if the user is already registered
const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email: email });
if (existingUser) {
return res.status(400).json({ message: "User already exists" });
}

// Create a new user if the user does not already exist
const user = new User({
name,
email,
password,
});
try {
const savedUser = await user.save();
res.json(savedUser);
} catch (error) {
res.status(400).json({ message: error.message });
}
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Can you see if it works if instead of responding with savedUser, write:
"res.json({savedUser});"

Comment: Still Getting The Same Error 'res.json({savedUser});'

Comment: Can you show the result of `console.log(req.body)`?